# iText7 for .NET SetAuthor() is Doubling the Author Value

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

When using the iText7 library to set a PDF document's properties the value for the builtin property author is getting doubled like '"Lastname, Firstname"; Lastname; Firstname'.  It should be 'Lastname, Firstname'.  It is getting the double quotes added, the name value twice and a comma changed to a semicolon. This has happened in two versions, 7.1.17 and 7.2.1.

The steps in creating the PDF are:

1. Use Microsoft.Interop.Word Document.ExportAsFixedFormat() to create the first PDF used by readerPDF.  This does not get the custom document properties to populate.  I need to set four custom properties used by a later step in this process.
2. Use iText7 to read the above PDF, add the custom document properties and also reset the built in properties and write that out to a second file accessed trough writerPDF.  iText7 only modifies a PDF by reading from file and writing to a second.

In step 2 the code calls the command to set the author property, PdfDocument.PdfDocumentInfo.SetAuthor(authorvalue);

The problem seems to only happen with commas in the author value, and I need the commas to do Lastname, Firstname. That is a requirement.  If I do not reset the property Author is has double quotes around it, that is not useful for our project.  All other properties, builtin and custom are working as expected.

The code looks like this:

```
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader readerPDF;
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter writerPDF;
string authorValue = "Lastname, Firstname";

readerPDF = new PdfReader(saveAsPathAndNameTemp);
writerPDF = new PdfWriter(pSavedPathAndPDFName);
PdfDocument pdfdocument = new PdfDocument(readerPDF, writerPDF);
PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfdocument.GetDocumentInfo();

info.SetAuthor(string.Empty);
info.SetAuthor(authorValue);

pdfdocument.Close();
readerPDF.Close();
writerPDF.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is issue in Adobe Acrobat reader. I used the next code to reproduce your issue on Java:

```
String filename = DESTINATION_FOLDER + "openSimpleDoc.pdf";
String author = "Test, Author";
String title = "Test, Title";
String subject = "Test, Subject";

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(filename));
pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo().setAuthor(author).setTitle(title).setSubject(subject);
pdfDoc.addNewPage();
pdfDoc.close();

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader);
Assert.assertEquals(author, pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo().getAuthor());
Assert.assertEquals(title, pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo().getTitle());
Assert.assertEquals(subject, pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo().getSubject());

pdfDoc.close();
```

As you can see, I didn't set the author twice and when I open the resulting PDF in Adobe Acrobat, I see that the author's name is enclosed in two quotes:

[image: Adobe Acrobat]

But in fact there are no two quotes. You can see it in PDF Studio, RUPS and Notepad++:

- [PDF Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwqK5.png)

  [image: PDF Studio]
- [RUPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBtIg.png)

  [image: RUPS]
- [Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GN1c.png)

  [image: Notepad++]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the main issue, the duplicating of the Author value if a comma was in the value. I updated the reference BouncyCastle.Crypto to 1.9.0.0. That resolved the main issue. the secondary issue of the double quotes in properties dialog box is address below by Nikita Kovaliov. I thank this poster for there input.